# track visitor set VPN or proxy ni php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to track in my page which user coming from original ip or which users are coming from proxy or VPN
i tried many functions and code but i not get what i want

i want like this

```
if($user == "RealIp"){
 echo "valid visitor"
}else{
echo "Please turn off your proxy or VPN"
}
```

i try this code before but nothing happen

```
function getUserIP()
{
    // Get real visitor IP behind CloudFlare network
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
        $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
    }
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
 if (get_ip_address() !== get_ip_address(true))
    {
        echo 'using proxy';
    }


function get_ip_address($proxy = false)
{
    if ($proxy === true)
    {
        foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED') as $key)
        {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true)
            {
                foreach (array_map('trim', explode(',', $_SERVER[$key])) as $ip)
                {
                    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 | FILTER_FLAG_IPV6 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false)
                    {
                        return $ip;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```